# How can I view a recent interaction between me and a user?

Tags: support, comment, search

I don't remember where I posted it, but I had a comment discussion with another user about the difference in the meaning of $\epsilon$. I don't know how to search for such a discussion.

Comment: Generally, "How to ... ?" questions fall under `support`, not `feature-request`. Sometimes they may lead to feature requests, if it turns out that the functionality isn't there, and is genuinely needed.

Comment: You can have a look at [your comments](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/91377/don-larynx?tab=activity&sort=comments) or, perhaps better, on the responses you received. ([This link](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/91377/don-larynx?tab=responses) might work, but you can find them under your profile page.) But it shows all comments/all responses. (But you can see names of users on your responses tab.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can:

- [search your comments by keyword](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/139760/my-comments-my-keyword) (the keyword can be the other user's display name, or something that was mentioned in the discussion)
- get the list of your [comments under posts by a specific user](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/142280/comments-to-specific-user)
- [browse all your comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/91377/don-larynx?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=4)